# Label Text not saving in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am Using Gridview in which i have one column of checkbox and  one of labels on checking the text of label is changing but when i am inserting it into database, it is taking default value of label.

Html

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" style="Text-align:center;">
     <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="changeTextValue(this); ChildCheckBox(this)"/>
             </ItemTemplate>
             <HeaderTemplate>
                 <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" OnClick="CheckAllEmp(this)"/>
             </HeaderTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField>
         <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="Status_Header" runat="server" Text="Status"/>
         <HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ClientIDMode="Static">0</asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my codebehind code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow g1 in grdData.Rows)
   {
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Real_Attendance"].ConnectionString);
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Attendanc (Stu_id,Status,time,Date,Sub_id) values (@Stu_id, @Status, @Time, @Date, @Sub_id)", con))
         {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stu_id", g1.Cells[3].Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", ((Label)(g1.FindControl("Label1"))).Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Session["Time_Value"].ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub_id", Session["Sub_id"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and see what `((Label)(g1.FindControl("Label1"))).Text` returns exactly? Also did you check the other parameter values?

Comment: i didn't get your question.

Comment: @user2747666: are you getting values for other controls ?

Comment: When are you calling your Code Behind Code ? any external Button Click, OR any GridView' Default Update button  etc.. ??

Comment: @Nadeem, Yes i am gettinf values of other controls

Comment: @FlopScientist
i am using External button for submitting the data

Comment: try setting EnableViewState="false" for Label and GridView once, to see if it works

Comment: if I am doing this Data is not going into Database

Comment: Is data NOT going only for a single Field or for All fields ?

Comment: Not going for every field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **HiddenField** to keep the same value with Label1.

**Gridview**

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ClientIDMode="Static">0</asp:Label>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value="0" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Javascript**

```
changeTextValue(obj)
{
    //in the end
    var Label1Value=1;//your Label1 value 
    $(obj).parents("tr").find("input[type=hidden]").val(Label1Value);
}
```

**C#**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", ((HiddenField)(g1.FindControl("HiddenField1"))).Value);
```